# count unique cities having total sales more than 50% in Power BI, DAX query

Tags: powerbi

Here is my data sample, of Table "Sales"

```
City    Items   Target  Sales
ABC     Pen     100     20
ABC     Pencil  200     40
ABC     Glue    100     68
CDE     Copy    50      37
CDE     Books   70      20
CDE     Rubber  200     156
```

I want a DAX query for Power BI, to count unique cities having total sales more than 50% for a large set of records with multiple Cities / States / Items

Comment: I am trying 
No. of Cities more than 50% Sales = CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT(Sales[City]),FILTER(Sales,DIVIDE(SUM('Sales'[Target]),SUM('Sales'[Sales]),0)>0.50)) 
but not getting expected resultSet as "1" (Only CDE with more than 50% sales)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You need to *iterate* over the distinct values of the `City` field, evaluate the *Sales % Target* for each `City`, then count the number of values exceeding 50%.

```
Cities >50% = 
    COUNTX (
        VALUES ( Sales[City] ),
        IF ( 
            CALCULATE ( 
                DIVIDE ( 
                    SUM ( Sales[Sales] ),
                    SUM ( Sales[Target] )
                )
             ) > 0.5,
            1
        )
    )
```